# Make my notification clickable

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I made an app with a notification that is triggered by an alarmmanager, only the notification is'nt clickable. How do I do this?

Code from MainActivity:

```
private void scheduleNotification(Notification notification, int delay) {

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationPublisher.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION_ID, 1);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION, notification);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    long futureInMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + delay;
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, futureInMillis, pendingIntent);
}

    private Notification getNotification(String titel, String content) {
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
    builder.setContentTitle(titel);
    builder.setContentText(content);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    return builder.build();
}
```

code from my notification publish class:

```
public class NotificationPublisher extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static String NOTIFICATION_ID = "notification-id";
public static String NOTIFICATION = "notification";

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
    int id = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
    notificationManager.notify(id, notification);

}
```

}

Comment: maybe you are loocking for this?   builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent); http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setContentIntent(android.app.PendingIntent)

Comment: What should it do when the user clicks on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for the method

```
setContentIntent(PROVIDE_YOUR_PENDING_INTENT);
```

You will need to provide a pending intent to where you want to redirect the user when he click on the notification.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setContentIntent(android.app.PendingIntent)